# Can I found player id from BaseGameActivity or GameHelper not just boolean if signing was ok?

Tags: android, google-play-services

Can I found player id from BaseGameActivity or GameHelper (https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init) ? Is there similar methods like in ios game center where I can get id and alias nit just boolean value does signing passed ok?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

`if (mSignedIn) {
       playerID = GameHelper.mGamesClient.getCurrentPlayerId();
    }`